# Querying a Threads Parameter using Context

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi, memory-management

I am trying to get a thread's parameter pointer by using the `GetThreadContext` API.

Here is an example:

```
function TestThread ( p : pointer ) : DWORD; stdcall;
begin
  while true do begin
    sleep (100);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ThreadID      : DWORD;
  ThreadHandle  : THandle;
  Test          : DWORD;
  ThreadContext : TContext;
begin
  Test          := 1337;  // Just for testing...
  ThreadHandle  := CreateThread(NIL, 0, @TestThread, Pointer(Test), CREATE_SUSPENDED, ThreadID);
  if ThreadHandle > 0 then begin
    if GetThreadContext(ThreadHandle, ThreadContext) then begin
      if ThreadContext.Ebx = Test then begin // This should match!
        Messagebox (0, 'Match!', '', 0);
      end else begin
        MessageBox(0, 'No Match!', '', 0);
      end;
    end;
    TerminateThread(ThreadHandle,0);
    CloseHandle(ThreadHandle); // Not sure if needed...
  end;
end;
```

It seems like that this doesn't work (`ThreadContext.Ebx` is not equal to my TestPointer).
Am I using it wrong? How do I get the parameter back using the Thread's Context?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not simply creating the thread, retrieve the parameter and then call [`SuspendThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345.aspx) on itself? This also prevents problems due to unsynchronized accesses.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense. A thread is defined as the unit of execution. If you do not provide a valid pointer to code, you do not have a thread. I suppose it would be a good idea that you stated the real problem you're trying to solve. Without using your proposed solution.

Comment: This thread will never run. You are reading fairly meaningless context information. It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish. If you need to implement IPC there are more appropriate ways to do so.

Comment: Why would you ever want to create a (costly) thread object to pass a single pointer to another process? Use a pipe, a Windows message, COM marshaling, or a shared memory segment. It's still unclear what you are ultimately trying to achieve.

Comment: @IInspectable I have removed all my comments.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain a little bit more about what your actual goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason at all to expect that the `EBX` register of a thread will contain the parameter passed to the thread procedure. The `EBX` register is a general purpose register and will contain whatever the thread happens to have last put in that register to do whatever it happens to be doing.

> How do I get the parameter back using the Thread's context?

You don't. The `CONTEXT` struct does not contain that information.

It is possible that you could find the stack frame associated with the call to `TestThread`. So long as the thread has not overwritten that part of the stack that was used to pass the parameter, it will contain the value you are interested in.

As it happens, in your code it seems to me that a thread that is created suspended will not actually have made it as far as the thread procedure. So even the method described above is not likely to work.

Comment: I am sorry. I just figured out the problem. I forgot to set the `ContextFlags` to `CONTEXT_FULL` before I get the ThreadContext! Should I delete my answer?

Comment: That won't help. You won't in general find the thread proc parameter in `EBX`.

Comment: You've tested on all versions of Windows? Try letting the thread run for a while. With some code that uses the `EBX` register. If your code can only work for a thread that is created suspended, there's not much point in you doing this at all. Presumably you are actually interested in suspending a running thread and inspecting it. And if you only want to use this with a thread that you create suspended, why would you bother calling `GetThreadContext` at all. Just remember what value you passed when you called `CreateThread`.

Comment: If you look in earlier revisions of my question I used to use RemoteThreads as a holder/dummy for a single pointer.

Comment: I tried to answer the question in front of me. I don't see any remote threads here. I think you should include the underlying goal in the question.

Comment: The user IInspectable suggested to use local creation of the threads. So I removed it, which kills the purpose of my question. I appreciate your answer though and is correctly answered to my question.